# Can a single VGA output provide independent images for 2 monitors?

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, vga

I once saw a cable splitter that came with a video card, and this card could feed 2 monitors with independent images with a single output connector (plus the special splitter). But the output was DVI.

I wonder if I could do the same thing with a VGA video card. If I have a standard video card with VGA output, there is any way to feed 2 monitors with independent images?

Comment: Also see this question: http://superuser.com/questions/69784/is-it-possible-to-drive-2-monitors-from-a-video-card-thats-designed-for-one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

You'll need either two cards, or a card with support of multiple monitors either with multiple connectors or a proprietary connector and an octopus cable splitting the multiple streams out from that.

[the basic VGA connector only supports a single video stream.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VGA_connector)

Comment: +1 very after the fact because I've never heard them called 'octopus cables'.