# Running third monitor, only dual head car

Tags: windows, multiple-monitors

I currently run a two screen setup using an nvidia fx570 on my work machine.

A third monitor is going to be available soon. Anyone know if you can combine a dual port video card and one of those usb-div or usb-vga adapters to run a third screen?

If not, any other ideas?

Thanks

Comment: See: http://superuser.com/questions/69784/is-it-possible-to-drive-2-monitors-from-a-video-card-thats-designed-for-one

Answer (score 2):

This may not be ideal if you don't also have a laptop but one solution I use relies on having another machine (old or a laptop) to attach the additional monitor. It's a software program called [MaxVista](http://www.maxivista.com/).

You install the server side of the program on your main machine and then up to three client instances on other machines. You can then use up to three aditional machines to view your desktop. For example I have a laptop to my left, dual monitors on my desktop and a second old PC with a large screen to my right.

Using MaxVista I have a continuous desktop that appears to my desktops as four monitors in the control panel.

Comment: Interesting one... i have a laptop right beside my workstation here... I'll check it out

Answer (score 1):

I know you can pick up a USB graphics adaptor: (new egg search VANTEC NBV-100U USB External Video Adapter for DVI or VGA Displays)

but it might be work checking out Matrox Dualhead2go or triplehead2go.  These actually take an output, and trick it into thinking the monitor has the resolution of two or 3 monitors, meaning you can spread a game across all 2 or 3.

http://www.matrox.com/graphics/en/