# Third monitor on onboard VGA?

Tags: multiple-monitors, integrated-graphics

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Can I use an onboard and pci vga simultaneously?](https://superuser.com/questions/44781/can-i-use-an-onboard-and-pci-vga-simultaneously)
>   [3 Monitors to a single pc](https://superuser.com/questions/136964/3-monitors-to-a-single-pc)

Hello guys,
I'am using dual monitor setup with a radeon 5770 vga card, also I have an onboard vga card on ASUS M4A785TD EVO mainboard. Now I want to add one more monitor to my system. Can I use the onboard vga for third monitor or I need to buy a new vga card? If I need to buy new vga card which one would you suggest for least price? I am using windows 7.

Comment: See - http://superuser.com/questions/44781/can-i-use-an-onboard-and-pci-vga-simultaneously or http://superuser.com/questions/112854/running-third-monitor-only-dual-head-car

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to. The 5770 supports [Eyefinity](http://sites.amd.com/us/underground/products/eyefinity/Pages/eyefinity.aspx), get an adapter for the display port output to the third monitor.